# Renamed folders are not installing after MSP patch installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, msi-patch

We have updated some folders in the new MSI like `Angular.min` to `Angular.min.1_5_19` which contains a file `Anguar.min.js`.

Created an `MSP` patch package to deliver it to customers. We can observe the change in the directory name in `ORCA` on applying `MSP` over old `MSI`, Also observed the updated log in `msimsp.log` file.

But after installing `MSP` in my machine, We are able to observe the new js file in the old folder itself. 
The new folder is neither created empty nor replaced the old folder with a new name.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer has the concept of component rules and things a minor upgrade / patch can and can't do and things that require a major upgrade. There is also a useful property called [MSIENFORCEUPGRADECOMPONENTRULES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/msienforceupgradecomponentrules) that causes an installer to fail and rollback when you break these rules rather then seeming to complete and doing most but not all that you asked for.

In this case you have probably broken a component rule by redefining the directory that a component belongs to.   The way to do this in a patch is:

1) Leave the old component in place.  Mark it as transitive and give it a condition that always evaluates to false.  This allows MSI to still properly track the component during the patch and remove it and it's old directory.

2) Create a new component for your new directory.  This allows MSI to install the new component and it's directory.